# Unable to Knit to pdf in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a .rmd file that knits fine to html but when I try to knit to pdf, it has this error message.

> Error in boxplot(sesame$bodydiff, sesame$letdiff, sesame$formdif, sesame$numbdif, :
>       object 'sesame' not found Call:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible 
>       -> eval -> eval -> boxplot

The object sesame is already in the code before this point. Note that this is the first plot I am attempting to add which may cause some sort of issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will need to add your code to the question so others can reproduce it. See `regex` for easy copy/paste of your existing code. Also provide session info (R version, RStudio version, packages, etc.) `sessionInfo()` can be used as well.

Comment: `regex` is regular repression, you may have meant `reprex`.

Comment: The .Rmd cannot be creating the object `sesame` if it is not found, regardless of output format. Perhaps that object is in your global environment, but not the environment created when knitr is run?

Comment: Boy do I feel sheepish. You are indeed correct. `reprex` is what I meant.